# check if a value exist in javascript array of object fetched from ajax response and delete it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

In the following code i am not able to filter entry.AllLinks.

The code is as follows:

```
 $.ajax({

    url:  url,
    type: "get",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function (data) {

        var c = [];
        var stringData = JSON.stringify(data.d.results[0].AllLinks);
        //alert(stringData);
        c.push(JSON.parse(stringData));
        alert(c);

        var xonly = c.filter(function (entry){
            return entry.AllLinks != x; 
        });
       alert(xonly);

    },
    error: function() {
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

}

It does not filter and when i hover cursor over AllLinks in entry.AllLinks it is undefined.
Value of entry is coming as:

```
 [{"AllLinks":"Link9","LinkURL":"http://www.Link9.com"},{"AllLinks":"Link6","LinkURL":"http://www.Link6.com"}]
```

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: I guess i need to split array and check if the key matches. Not sure how to do this

Comment: How do I access values like Link9 and Link6 and get their index to remove them from array?

Comment: have you done any googling or research?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide example of your code as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter` to filter the array as per the `values` you require.

```js
let arr = [{"AllLinks":"Link9","LinkURL":"http://www.Link9.com"},{"AllLinks":"Link6","LinkURL":"http://www.Link6.com"}] ;

arr = arr.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.AllLinks !== 'Link9';
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thats correct if snippet is run but its not working for my code

Comment: If you look in my answer `arr` is an array. `filter` is present in `array` only. `c=data.d.results[0].AllLinks;` - Here you are extracting `AllLinks` from the response. You should probably `console.log(c)` after doing this to check if `c` contains array which you need to filter or not.

Comment: No its not an array.How to proceed if not an array?Any idea?

Comment: In your question, it is an array of elements. Why don't you try to apply filter to `data.d.results`. You should probably update your question with the correct data